# quicksort in ML

Tags: quicksort, sml, smlnj, ml

Without using case expressions (that comes in the next section of the class), I can't see why the following doesn't do a quicksort. It goes into a loop somewhere and never ends.

splitAt and append have already been thorughly tested, but here are the codes for them.

```
fun append(xs, ys) =
if null xs
then ys
else (hd xs) :: append(tl xs, ys)

fun splitAt(xs : int list, x : int) =
let
    fun sp(ys : int list, more : int list, less : int list) =
        if null ys
        then (more, less)
        else
            if hd ys < x
            then sp(tl ys, more, append(less, [hd ys]))
            else sp(tl ys, append(more, [hd ys]), less)
in
    sp(xs, [], [])
end

fun qsort(xs : int list) = 
  if length xs <= 1
  then xs
  else 
    let
        val s = splitAt(xs, hd xs)
    in
        qsort(append(#2 s, #1 s))
    end
```

And I get the same problem using append(qsort(#2 s), qsort(#1 s)), but I though the former was better style since it only require a single recursion with each round.
I guess I should say that 'splitAt' divides the list into greater than or equal to the second argument, and less than, and creates a tuple). Append concatenates 2 lists.

PS: This is only a practice problem, not a test or homework.

Comment: You need to provide the code for `splitAt` and `append`. If the code is buggy, the bug might be there. Having said that -- wouldn't something like `append(qsort (#2 s), qsort(#1 s))` make more sense?

Answer (score 2):

> It goes into a loop somewhere and never ends.

Your problem is most likely `qsort` being called on a list that does not reduce in size upon recursive call. Perhaps go with `append(qsort (#2 s), qsort (#1 s))`. But even then, can you be sure that each of `#1 s` and `#2 s` will always reduce in size?

Ideally you should supply `splitAt` and `append` since they're not library functions. You might consider using the built-in append called `@` and the built-in `List.partition` to form `splitAt`.

Compare against this one found somewhere on the interwebs:

```
fun quicksort [] = []
  | quicksort (x::xs) =
    let
      val (left, right) = List.partition (fn y => y < x) xs
    in
      quicksort left @ [x] @ quicksort right
    end
```

Comment: I don't want to use pattern match, because that comes in the next chapter and these problems are supposed to be done with our current tools. But converting what you wrote, it is the same as my qsort with the final statement as append(qsort(#2 s), qsort(#1 s)) which again gives an infinite loop.

Comment: As I said, this is probably because one of the sides never reduces in size just like `qsort`ing the entire list again will surely not reduce in size. Compared to the version given in my answer, removing `x` from the input list every time will ensure that subsequent calls to `quicksort` has fewer elements than before.

Answer (score 0):

Since this isn't homework ...

Note that if `xs = [1,2]` then `splitAt(xs hd xs)` returns `([1,2],[])` so the attempt to sort `[1,2]` by this version of `qsort` reduces to ... sorting `[1,2]` again. That will never terminate.

Instead, I would advocate applying `splitAt` to the *tail* of the xs. A minimal tweak to your code is to leave `append` and `splitAt` alone but to rewrite `qsort` as:

```
fun qsort(xs : int list) = 
  if length xs <= 1
  then xs
  else 
    let
        val s = splitAt(tl xs, hd xs)
    in
        append(qsort(#2 s), (hd xs) :: qsort(#1 s))
    end;
```

Then, for example,

```
- qsort [4,2,1,2,3,6,4,7];
val it = [1,2,2,3,4,4,6,7] : int list
```

It is crucial that you apply `qsort` twice then append the results. Tryng to apply `qsort` once to the appended split would be trying to reduce `qsort` to applying `qsort` to a list which is the same size as the original list.

SML really becomes fun when you get to pattern matching. You should enjoy the next chapter.

Comment: Indeed that works and I thank you. I see that you do have to apply qsort twice and the simple change of using tl xs in splitAt made a big difference as well. SML is indeed fun, interesting and educational.

Comment: @NealKoss: "the simple change of using `tl xs` in `splitAt` made a big difference as well": No, that + using `(hd xs) :: ...` in the result made *the* difference. By this device, John makes sure that when `qsort` calls itself twice, each of those calls happens with a fewer number of arguments than before. That way he ensures an upper bound on how many recursive calls the function can make. Can you see how many that is? And yes, SML is indeed fun! :) (As long as annoying people on the Internet isn't making you do math!)